# Creating an event-management/signup web application

Tags: python, web-applications, web

I intend to create an event management system, where users may login, view a list of events, sign up to volunteer at events, cancel registration, and view a calendar view of events of the day. In addition, users should receive emails, notifying them when the event(s) they have signed up for is coming up.

Primarily, it should be accessible through a browser, but I would like, in the future, for it to become an organization-wide iPad app.

I have a few questions. How should I store my data? Will MySQL be sufficient? Is it better if I sign up for a service like Heroku, Appfog, or GAE? If I don't need these services, would it be able to run if I used my shared hosting plan over at GoDaddy?

I was thinking about using Google Drive Spreadsheets to store data, and using [Google's spreadsheet API](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/spreadsheets/) to access and write to it. Are there any advantages or disadvantages of taking this route?

Only 50 or so people would need to access it.

I like Python, but haven't done much on the web. Is [web2py](http://www.web2py.com/) a good idea, or is it overkill for my purposes?

For UI, I was leaning towards HTML + jQuery + AJAX? + Bootstrap.

Thanks!

Comment: there are going to be many solutions for what you want, i believe that you can use the same go-daddy shared space and put your code on the same server and add a sub-domain to that.
also, i have tried web2py and i looks like a good idea and if you want you can also try django, it is pretty famous as well. I was trying the google webapi but i found it little difficult to understand..

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you to use Django, which is a macro framework written in Python to develop web applications.

Database is of your choice like mysq, postgresql or by default you can use the sqlite3 database offered by Django.

The same goes with UI. You can use the technologies like html, js, CSS, jQuery, bootstrap etc.

Hope this helps.